# state won't update inside react function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, react-state

I'm building a Blackjack game in React.js. And I have set the state to an array of type cards. It looks like this.

```
    let startingDealerHand: Cards[] = dealCards(2, []);
    let startingPlayerHand: Cards[] = dealCards(2, []);
    const [dealerHand, setDealerHand] = useState<Array<Cards>>(startingDealerHand);
    const [playerHand, setPlayerHand] = useState<Array<Cards>>(startingPlayerHand);
```

I'm trying to update the state inside of an onclick function that looks like this.

```
takeHit={(hand: Cards[]) => setPlayerHand(dealCards(1, hand))}
```

I tried debugging the application and onClick is doing what it is supposed to do, however the ui as well as the state isn't updating for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
onClick={(hand: Cards[]) => setPlayerHand(dealCards(1, hand))}
```

or:

```
onClick={() => handleTakeHit(hand)}
```

and above, just under where your useState consts are created, add:

```
const handleTakeHit = (hand:Cards[]) => {
    setPlayerHand(dealCards(1, hand) )
}
```